# use CSS/LESS to add built-in checkbox to first column of table

Tags: html, css, checkbox, less

I am new to CSS/LESS, and am wondering that is it possible to build a `checked-box-table` class that adds checkbox to the first column by default? In other words, if the user has the following html:

```
<table class="checked-box-table">
    <tr>
        <th>header 1</th>
        <th>header 2</th>
        <th>header 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1 </td>
        <td>2 </td>
        <td>3 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the user will see a column of checkbox before "header 1" and "1".

A follow-up question:
If this is possible, then is it possible to further style the checkbox and its containing cell inside the "checked-box-table" LESS? (say, define the width/height of checkbox, and the cell should be tight around the checkbox, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part of your question, I believe [:first-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) is what you are looking for.

In this specific case, what you want is

```
.checked-box-table th:first-child, .checked-box-table td:first-child {
 /* styles */
}
```

As for the checkbox first column, there is no way using CSS/LESS to add HTML to your template. You would have to manually input another `<th>` and `<td>` with an `<input type="checkbox">` in each cell.

```
<table class="checked-box-table">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
    <th>header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>1 </td>
    <td>2 </td>
    <td>3 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you choose to do this, the `<th>header 1</th>` and `<td>1 </td>` are no longer the first children, so you must use the `:nth-child` selector.

```
.checked-box-table th:nth-child(2), .checked-box-table td:nth-child(2) {
 /* styles */
}
```

Edit: Thank you [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max) for pointing out the `:nth-child` selector.

Comment: "there is no `:second-child` selector" - there's actually: `:nth-child(2)`. (But I suppose it's not that important since the main point of the OP question is in its first part.)

Answer (score 1):

In simple words: no, CSS is for styling existing HTML elements. It cannot add or remove anything, neither affect HTML structure in any other way. (It's possible to "hide" something though).